# How accurate is P3 Plugin profiler

Tags: performance

How accurately does the P3 Plugin Profiler plugin measure the loading time of plugins, and what mechanism does it uses to estimate the loading time?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this page from GoDaddy: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/7360/using-the-wordpress-plugin-performance-profiler-p3

It gives a pretty good overview of the P3 Plugin Profiler and should be able to answer your questions. There's definitely error involved, and it should really just be used as a guideline.

Comment: Lone link is considered a poor answer (see [help > deleted answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. Please try to include at least summary of information you are linking to.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to run the profiling process at least a few times over a couple of days to actually get an accurate result. It isn't just the plugin but other factors such as the varying performance level of your hosting.

For accurate answers, I would recommend triangulating your results by using:

**- P3 Plugin Profiler
 - Google speed test
 - Yahoo's Yslow**

Combining these, or other tools, will help give you a more accurate profile of your website/webpage.

Best of luck.